# Android - Json and TwitterFeed code

Tags: android, json, twitter

Hi this is my first app.
I am a beginner when it comes to programming and to android. 
My app is similar to the twitter app. But instead of getting values from twitter it would get values from my database. The app will be loaded with images and links to web pages.

My question.
Lets say my app is on the app store and someone downloads it.
My app get most of its content from my mysql db via Json. Every time i add new content to the db, must the user update the app to get the new content or will it automatically update its self.

Can someone just take a look at my code. I am not sure about the Async() and the doInBackground(). If you have any other helpful coding suggestions please let me know. I would like to put this app on the app store when it is complete.

Kind regards

```
public class TwitterFeedActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new MyTask().execute();
    }
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(TwitterFeedActivity.this,
                    "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://myurl.com");
                HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);

                if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                {
                    String result = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
                    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray sessions = root.getJSONArray("results");

                    for (int i = 0; i < sessions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject session = sessions.getJSONObject(i);
                        Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
                        tweet.n_text = session.getString("n_text");
                        tweet.n_name = session.getString("n_name");
                        tweet.Image = session.getString("Image");
                        tweets.add(tweet);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TwitterFeedActivity", "Error loading JSON", e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            setListAdapter(new TweetListAdaptor(TwitterFeedActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, tweets));
        }
    }

    private class TweetListAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {
        private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;
        public TweetListAdaptor(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Tweet> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.tweets = items;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }
            final Tweet o = tweets.get(position);
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
            TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
            bt.setText(o.n_name);
            tt.setText(o.n_text);
            image.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(o.Image));

            image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(o.n_text));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            return v;
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(String bitmapUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(bitmapUrl);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream()); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {return null;}
    }
}
```

Comment: first make sure you are getting response from tweeter server or not in doInBackground ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am posting the Async related code. I hope, you will find it helping. First of all, make a class as follows:

```
package com.example.pre;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;




import android.util.Log;

public class JSONFunctions {

    public String CreateCon(String url){
        String res="";
        try{
            URL u=new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.
                    openConnection();

                res=readStream(con.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       




        return res;
    }

    private String readStream(InputStream is) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String result = "";
        BufferedReader reader=null;
          try{
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result=result+line;
                }
          }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }finally{
            if(reader!=null)
            {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Second in your main class, paste the following method:

```
 private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        readJson();
            //progress_dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONFunctions jsonf=new JSONFunctions();
        str1=jsonf.CreateCon(cat_url);
        return null;
    }
}
```

where readJson is the method where you define your functionality and str1 is the string where you provide the address of the json. Don't forget call to the PostExecute class.